# Edits to a spatial dataframe dont carry over when exporting to a featureclass in ArcPy, why?

Tags: python, arcpy, pandas

I created a `spatial dataframe` from a `featureclass`. Then I edited the spatial dataframe, and exported it back to a featureclass. I was expecting the `attribute table` of the featureclass to keep the results of the spatial dataframe but that wasn't the case. Instead, some column names retreated back to their original names and those that did, didn't carry over the values.

Why is the `spatial dataframe` not correctly exporting to the `attribute table` in the `featureclass`?

Code:

```
import arcpy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import arcgis
from arcpy.sa import *
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.mapping import WebMap
from arcgis.features import GeoAccessor, GeoSeriesAccessor

# create spatial dataframe
sdf_AllThinningPlots = pd.DataFrame.spatial.from_featureclass("studyArea_AllThinningPlots")

# drop columns
sdf_AllThinningPlots = sdf_AllThinningPlots[['OBJECTID_1', 'Project_Na', 'Project_Nu', 'Annual_Yea', 'Treatment', 'Percent_Tr', 'Mapping_Me', 'Seeded', 'Shape_Leng', 'SHAPE']]

# rename columns
sdf_AllThinningPlots.rename(columns={
    'Project_Na': 'Project',
    'Annual_Yea': 'Year',
    'Project_Nu': 'Project_Number',
    'Percent_Tr' : 'Pct_Treated',
    'Mapping_Me' : 'Mapping_Method',
    'OBJECTID_1' : 'OBEJECTID'
}, inplace=True)

# Export to featureclass
sdf_AllThinningPlots.spatial.to_featureclass(location=r"C:\dougals_fir_reg_research\data\test_AllThinnningPlots.shp")
```

Spatial Dataframe:
[image]

The attribute table of the featureclass **after** exported to a featureclass from a spatial dataframe

[image]

Comment: It looks like the data frame from feature class is a one way relationship, try making the changes in arcpy before generating the data frame. It is also possible that arcpy isn't aware of changes made by other software, I've seen a rare few examples of such in practice, the only fix is to use one API to import, make changes and then export and use the other package after all the changes have been committed to disc.

Comment: To simplify your code snippet I think you should remove any imports that are not used within it.

Comment: Shapefile do not support long names for fields. May be a reason why data are missing as well.